# Performing function to see if JSON file includes specific strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function

My local JSON file contains documents (ending in .docx, .pdf, etc). I have a table that's rendering those documents and I want to be able to render the text '.docx' (and what not) into a separate column, with each text string corresponding to a document. The end goal is to replace the texts with their respective icons, i.e. a MS Word one for .docx.

So far I have an `.includes('docx' || 'DOCX' || 'pptx')` method that correctly shows the values as true and false in the table's column:

> |true||Example.docx|
>
> |false||Other.popx|

How can I include a loop (or something else) in the code I have to display the texts of 'docx', 'pptx', etc. instead of true and false?

#### Loading doc title data:

```
loadTableData() {
    $.noConflict();
    let tableRes = KMdocs.d.results.filter(function(val) { 
      return (val.FileLeafRef.trim().length > 0);
    }).map(function(obj) {
      return {
        "Path": obj.EncodedAbsUrl,
        "Titles": obj.File.Name,
        "Categories": obj.ResourceType.results.map(function(val) {
          return val.Label;
        }).join(";"),
        "Blank": "",
        "docImg": obj.File.Name.includes('docx' || 'DOCX' || 'pptx')
        // ----- this is where I'd like to include the code
      }
    })
```

#### Rendering table data:

```
$('#km-table-id').DataTable( {
      columns: [
        // { data: "Blank" },
        { data: "Categories" }, // hidden
        { data: "docImg" },
        { data: "Titles" } // must be in last position to respond w/ checkboxes
      ],
      columnDefs: [
...etc
```

Comment: What about replacing `obj.File.Name.includes('docx' || 'DOCX' || 'pptx')` with `getFileExtension(obj.File.Name)`, and letting that function return the appropriate string?

Comment: please dont add a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563037/getting-specific-strings-document-extensions-from-local-json-file) twice if you are not getting a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will filter for `docx` and `pptx` and then return the value if it's provided

```
function documentType(fileName) {
  return [fileName].filter(function(filter) {
    return filter.toLowerCase().includes('docx') || filter.toLowerCase().includes('pptx')
  }).map(function(filename) {
    //Get File Extension
    return filename.split('.').pop();
  }).pop();
}
```

Usage would be:

```
"docImg": documentType(obj.File.Name)
```